# How to create new date rows for each unique value in column?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have some data that looks like this. Jan-2019 to June-2021

```
date = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 29)

productB = rep("B",29)
productB = rep("B",29)
productA = rep("A",29)
productA = rep("A",29)

subproducts1=rep("1",29)
subproducts2=rep("2",29)
subproductsx=rep("x",29)
subproductsy=rep("y",29)

b1 <- c(rnorm(29,5))
b2 <- c(rnorm(29,5))
b3 <-c(rnorm(29,5))
b4 <- c(rnorm(29,5))


dfone <- data.frame("date"= rep(date,4),
                "product"= c(rep(productB,1),rep(productA,1)),
                "subproduct"= 
                  c(subproducts1,subproducts2,subproductsx,subproductsy),
                "actuals"= c(b1,b2,b3,b4))
dfone
```

I was wondering how I can add new dates up to 12-2022 for each unique subproduct with the product and subproduct intact but the value = 0 for new dates created? So my data ends at June 2021, I want new rows July 2021..... to Dec 2022 with their respective product/subproduct with value = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `tidyr::complete()` with `nesting()` and `fill = list()` argument

```r
library(tidyr)

dfone %>%
  complete(date = seq.Date(from = max(date), to = as.Date('2022-12-01'), by = 'month'), 
           nesting(product, subproduct), fill = list(actuals = 0))
#> # A tibble: 192 x 4
#>    date       product subproduct actuals
#>    <date>     <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>
#>  1 2021-05-01 A       2             5.12
#>  2 2021-05-01 A       y             4.33
#>  3 2021-05-01 B       1             4.50
#>  4 2021-05-01 B       x             7.01
#>  5 2021-06-01 A       2             0   
#>  6 2021-06-01 A       y             0   
#>  7 2021-06-01 B       1             0   
#>  8 2021-06-01 B       x             0   
#>  9 2021-07-01 A       2             0   
#> 10 2021-07-01 A       y             0   
#> # ... with 182 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Quick data manipulation question. If I have a column in a dataframe with dates in this format "201901" how can I convert it to year month day?

Comment: paste `01` in the end and then parse `as.date` or using `lubridate::ymd()`

Comment: Hey I had a new problem that arised. Say I have now a new column called "scenario" with 96 "scenario1" strings and 96 "scenario2" strings to make 192 rows. These scenarios have different max dates. How can I adjust this to have max dates for both scenario 1 and 2 instead of just for the max date for both?

Comment: group by on this scenario column before complete, @chriswang123456

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. So if I use this group_by can I also create dynamic time series where the start and end dates differ for each scenario? Also the subproducts are start and end times are different as well, so I should group_by subproducts as well?